# Specified cast is not valid in linq-to-sql query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
IQueryable<roleTableField> manyRoleTab;
manyRoleTab = from dat in roleTabTable1
              where dat.RoleId == kv.Value 
              select dat;
```

Returns an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Here `roleTableField` is my table class, i am using `LINQ-to-Sql`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *IQueryable<manyRoleTab1>* ?

Comment: Are you sure dat is of type roleTableField?  Is RoleId the same type as kv.Value?  If you change the declaration to var manyRoleTab = ... and then look at the datatype in the debugger, what is it?

Comment: Tim,yes RoleID and kv.value having same type as "string".

Comment: sorry, i meant Paddy...

Comment: No Alireza, I think IQueryable<type> should be of table class type.